# Print nice old drugstore bottle labels with LaTeX

Tags: labels

I'd like to print some nice looking old school drugstore bottle labels (they would look great in my kitchen).

Here I found some of the labels I had in mind:

[image]

[image]

http://www.stylingfieber.de/2013/09/helden-des-alltagsolanisi.html

Now I am wondering if (and how) it is possible to achieve something like that, maybe just with a  rectangular design, since this would be more easy.
I think there are tow tasks to perform on this one.

At first I have to find some blank labels I can print on and transform the labels outline into LaTeX.

Secondly I need do design a label like in the pictures.

For task one i was looking at the [`ticket`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ticket) package
and for task two I have no idea.

Do anyone of you have any good idea, maybe someone already tried what I want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is 'pretty' easy with `tcolorbox` and using `angular arc` option, the background colour etc, the borderline width, inset etc. can be changed at will.

The `tcbraster` environment is a nice way to ensure some layout, i.e. for adhesive label sheets etc.

Do not forget to compile twice to get the `raster` layout working!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{skins,raster}

\newtcolorbox{apothekenetikett}[1][]{%
  colback={white!50!yellow},
  boxrule=0pt,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  colframe=black,
  fontupper={\huge \bfseries\sffamily},
  borderline={2pt}{4pt}{black},
  halign=center,
  width=8cm, auto outer arc,
  arc=4mm,
  valign=center,arc is angular,#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2,raster equal height]
\begin{apothekenetikett}
INGWER
\end{apothekenetikett}
\begin{apothekenetikett}
  GUMMI ARABICUM
\end{apothekenetikett}
\begin{apothekenetikett}
SALZ
\end{apothekenetikett}
\begin{apothekenetikett}
KURKUMA
\end{apothekenetikett}
\begin{apothekenetikett}
GARAM MASALA
\end{apothekenetikett}
\begin{apothekenetikett}
THYMIAN
\end{apothekenetikett}
\begin{apothekenetikett}
KORIANDER
\end{apothekenetikett}
\end{tcbraster}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: sadly i get a lot of errors, like:    "Unknown option `most' for package `tcolorbox'". and    "Environment tcbraster undefined."

Comment: @John.Doe_876: Try to update. Current `tcolorbox` version is `3.90`, but there are other ways. I will change to a version which should be compilable

Comment: @John.Doe_876: See the update: `\tcbuselibrary{skins,raster}` is what you need here

Comment: Yes this works pretty nice.   Thank you from there on i can start with finding some nice labels.

Comment: @John.Doe_876: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!

Comment: with  `\begin{apothekenetikett}
INGWER \\[-15 pt]
\begin{footnotesize}
12.06.17
\end{footnotesize}
\end{apothekenetikett}`  you can even ad a use-by date

Comment: @John.Doe_876: Well, yes -- I leave that to you of course. In my household `spices` are used before they are ruined ;-)